# py2neo v3 cypher keyError

Tags: py2neo

I'm a newbe with py2neo.
Trying to create a cypher statement to which includes some sort of selection like

`query = 'MATCH (p:Person {name:"Alice"}) - [r] - b) RETURN p,r,b'
    res = Graph.run(query)`

I'm getting a `KeyError: 'name'`

Running the same query directly in neo4j shell or web client runs successfully.

#### Update

I manage to run the code using the `WHERE` statement:
`query = ('MATCH (p:Person) - [r] - b)
             WHERE p.name="Alice" 
             RETURN p,r,b')
res = Graph.run(query)`

Is this the only option to run py2neo queries or is there a way to use the key values of the node properties?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second node b should be enclosed by parenthesis (). I've also created a graph object from the Graph class:

```
from py2neo import Graph
neo4j_config = dict(
    user="neo4j",
    password="neo4j_pwd"
)
graph = Graph(**neo4j_config)
query = 'MATCH (p:Person {name:"Alice"}) - [r] - (b) RETURN p,r,b'
res = graph.run(query)
```